# Using Microsoft ClearScript i want to execute C#/VbScript from the java script. and how to execute dynamic C#/Vb code in ClearScript

Tags: clearscript

Using Microsoft ClearScript i want to execute C#/VbScript from the java script. and how to execute dynamic C#/Vb code in ClearScript.

I need to execute vbscript/C# code from javascript after click of save button.

Comment: Please be more specific. Have you looked at [ClearScript's tutorial](https://microsoft.github.io/ClearScript/Tutorial/FAQtorial.html)?

Comment: Clearscript allows you to run VBS/JS from C#, not the other way round.  And if you are talking about webpage, no, you can't call .Net from a browser, outside of ActiveX.  What exactly do you want to do?